# Ansible: apply IAM role to ec2 machine while deployment using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am planning to use Ansible as solution for deploying ec2 machines. I have attached IAM role for the master machine with appropriate permissions.
I can attach security groups, tags, elastic IP etc by defining tags in playbook.
Now, while deploying a new ec2 instance using playbook, can I attach a specific IAM role, for example, which has access to a given S3 bukcet or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. The parameter is called `instance_profile_name`

> instance_profile_name - Name of the IAM instance profile to use.

```
- ec2:
    key_name: mykey
    group: databases
    instance_type: t2.micro
    instance_profile_name: S3Role
    ...
```